# Use GetProperties() in LINQ Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

A simple description of my problem: Let's say I have two classes, Class1 and Class 2, that both implement the same interface, which has the following fields:

string FieldA;

string FieldB;

For legacy reasons, Class1 uses FieldA for a certain purpose that is opposite the way Class2 uses it. In fact, Class2 uses FieldB for the same data that Class1 would use FieldA, and vice versa: the fields are switched on the classes.

I need to be able to specify which field to use in the left hand side of the Where clause of a LINQ query before it is passed to Entity Framework. If I use reflection via GetProperties() it simply passes the Func to the database before it evaluates and I get an exception. How can I dynamically decide which field to use?

Comment: Decorate your fields with a custom attribute. At the point of execution, pick up the attributes from reflection *before* execution, and ascertain who is who, and pass in the correct property value into the method. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using something like this:

```
var query = from obj in yourCollection
    let left = obj is ClassA ? obj.Field1 : obj.Field2
    where left == /* your condition goes here */
    select /* anything you want to select */;
```

You can also invoke GetProperties() in let clause to get what you want if the method above is not enough.